# Wordpress: How to programmatically add post for each day?

Tags: php, wordpress, bulkinsert

I would like to know if there is a possibility to have a script that creates automatically daily posts "from today" to "end date" (manually set in the script). So at each iteration post_date would be $date +1day.

First i don't know if this script must be executed in functions.php or elsswhere...

Second, i am newbie in php, so i have understood how to create 1 single post with "wp_insert_post" but i don't understand how to insert it in a loop.

Looking for help, if someone has an idea...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Of course we can do it.
From digging through /wp-includes/post.php, It looks like you may need to follow few steps:

1. set your post_status to future.
2. set the post_date to when you want it published.
3. insert the post as your code shows.

   ```
   function daily_post_article() {

           $begin = new DateTime("2018-11-01");
           $end = new DateTime("2018-12-15");

           $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString("1 day");
           $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

           foreach ($period as $dt) {
               $publishDate = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
               $postTitle = "Daily Post Title => ".$publishDate;

               if ( !get_page_by_title( $postTitle, "OBJECT", "post" ) ){
                   $args = array(
                       "post_title"=> "Daily Post Title => ".$publishDate, 
                       "post_type"=>"post", 
                       "post_date" => $publishDate,
                       "post_status"=>"future"
                   );        
                   $time = strtotime( $postdate . " GMT" );
                   $post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );
                   wp_schedule_single_event( $time, "publish_future_post", array( $post_id ) );
               }
           }
   }
   add_action("wp", "daily_post_article");
   ```
4. Each post will be automatically published on selected date.
5. This features provided by WordPress.

Comment: thanks a lot but can i use it without a CRON by excepting the script just once time and creating posts as many posts from "today" to "END date" .?

Comment: Please add this code to functions.php file of you currently activated theme, Please let me know if you face any issues.